# When does IIS resets session variables?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session, iis-7

In my website I want to know when a client is logged out. In order to do so the client will be constantly sending a request to the website saying "hey I am logged in". The moment a client stops sending that request the website will assume that the client has been disconnected and will save those changes in the database.

**So my question is** if a client just send a request to the website could IIS reset session variables in the next minute?. Maybe IIS will not reset session variables n minutes after receiving a request? Should I create a windows service instead to be 100% sure?

Comment: the session, on the server, is controlled by settings at the IIS level, on the WebSite itself. Here's a link on how to set that session timeout property on your site: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: You cannot guarantee when the session will end.  IIS controls this, and it can reset the session whenever it feels like.  Session configuration settings in IIS are at best "suggestions" to IIS.  You should never design your application to depend on the session being there for the length the user is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS resets session variables only when the session ends.

> Maybe IIS will not reset session variables n minutes after receiving a request?

The session ends when the timeout occurs, so your n is the timeout defined for your session.

> Should I create a windows service instead to be 100% sure?

I think you can do it without a windows service.

This article can help you [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)